# Calling \psfrag{} inside a for loop for figure with monotonically increasing names

Tags: loops, psfrag

First of all my question is different from this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156552/calling-psfrag-inside-a-forloop). The issue is that in my case I want to loop figures that are named with a monotonically increasing order from `(1,2,\ldots,1000)`. I know how to use `\psfrag` for editing a single `.eps` file. But, what I don't know is how to do the same for multiple figures. As said earlier, in my case only the figure number changes (increases monotonically) and everything else remains the same.

Is it possible to loop this execution inside a loop? Since, I have never worked with loops in latex, at this moment I have no MWE.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Could you give feedback for the solution please?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, I will work this out tonight and will give you the feedback, because when I plan to work on the solution, I saw found the solution disappeared, and for some reason, I am seeing it today, So, I will work this out today, and will give the feedback.

Comment: I've had an error in my first version, deleted it and improved it.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks!1, Could you also tell me what is the upper bound on such iterations i.e., the maximum limit for the loops?

Comment: The upper bound should be limited by the maximum number of a counter value, i.e. 2^{31}-1, since I am pretty sure that the `\foreach` loop uses a count (register) internally

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270536/31729 for example on the maximum counter value

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That's all I need :), now I can go and finish my presentation in a swift with this looping technique (hopefully).

Comment: I doubt that you would have about 2 billion slides then, so you're on the safe side ;-) Happy TeXing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way with `\foreach` from `pgffor` package running a loop.

It uses the iterations from `1` to `20`, applies the `psfrag` replacements and includes the relevant `fooX.eps` file. where X stands for any integer number between 1 and 20.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {1,...,20} {%
  \psfrag{LATEX}{\bfseries \huge \LaTeX2e\  from file foo\x}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.6,angle=-90]{foo\x}

}

\end{document}
```

The `foo.eps` file is a simple `.eps` file generated with gnuplot. 
Here is a [DropBox - Link to foo.eps](https://www.dropbox.com/s/co7azv3fmig2z5m/foo.eps?dl=0) (The other fooX.eps are just copies, for sake of simplicity)

[image]

Comment: Fantastic!! is the feedback, works like a charm!!!!